# Filters not executed in JAX-RS for 4xx errors

Tags: java, filter, jersey, jax-rs

I have implemented the ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter for intercepting the request/responses. This works fine for normal requests/responses.

But for 4xx errors, the filter does not get executed/triggered. I tried the `@PreMatching` filter and setting the `@Priority` to as low as possible, still I find that the filter is not getting executed.

I need to be able to capture the request/response body for the following errors as well:

```
   BAD_REQUEST(400, "Bad Request"),
   UNAUTHORIZED(401, "Unauthorized"),
   FORBIDDEN(403, "Forbidden"),
   NOT_FOUND(404, "Not Found"),
   NOT_ACCEPTABLE(406, "Not Acceptable"),
   CONFLICT(409, "Conflict"),
   GONE(410, "Gone"),
   PRECONDITION_FAILED(412, "Precondition Failed"),
   UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE(415, "Unsupported Media Type")
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a filter?

EDIT: Adding the filter code.

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
@Priority(20)
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter,
    WriterInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingFilterTrial.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) throws IOException {
        logRequest(reqContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
        ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        // aroundWriteTo will not be called for empty body
        if(containerResponseContext.getEntity() == null) {
            logResponse(null, containerRequestContext);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            logResponse(context, null);
    }

    private void logRequest(ContainerRequestContext reqContext)
        throws IOException {
            //body
            byte[] requestBody = getRequestBody(reqContext);
    }

    private void logResponse(WriterInterceptorContext context , ContainerRequestContext reqContext)
        throws IOException {

            byte[] responseBody = new byte[0];
            //we pass context as null for empty body
            if (context != null) {
                responseBody = getResponseBody(context);
            }
    }


    private byte[] getRequestBody(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) throws IOException {
            byte[] reqBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(reqContext.getEntityStream());
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(reqBytes);
            reqContext.setEntityStream(in);
            return reqBytes;
    }

    private byte[] getResponseBody(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException {
        OutputStream originalStream = context.getOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        context.setOutputStream(baos);
        try {
            context.proceed();
        } finally {
            baos.writeTo(originalStream);
            baos.close();
            context.setOutputStream(originalStream);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show this filter and all of your app configurations? Not much we can do without more info. This is not a normal situation. We would need as much information as possible to be able to reproduce the problem. If you could make a minimal GitHub repo that we could run and see the problem, that would be ideal. Without that, I don't know if I can reproduce this problem. I've never heard of this happening to anyone before.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha added.